# Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Find the integral: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)^2}\,dx$$

UPD.
I want to calculate this using residues, and I have a problem with it. I guess, firstly, we can get rid of $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator. Let $u=\sqrt{x}$. Then $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)^2}\,dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log u}{(1+u^2)^2}\,du$. Then we will take a semisircle centered at 0 in the upper half-plane, with radius $R\to \infty$ . Then $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log u}{(1+u^2)^2}\,du =\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{[-R,R]} \frac{\log z}{(1+z^2)^2}\,dz + A$, where $A\to 0$. And here my problem, to use a residues, we need to do something with $\ln$, but I dont know what exactly. I know that $\log z=\log |z| + i\Delta argz$. In this case $i\Delta argz=i\pi$ but what should I do with the first summand

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: ... indeed, show your work, and how do you know it didn't work?

Comment: this integral doesn't converge on the given interval

Comment: Consider the function $f(z)=\frac{\ln z}{\sqrt{z}(1+z)^2}$. So, this function has only one singular point is $z=0$. Then using theorem about residues we can write $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln z}{\sqrt{z}(1+z)^2}=2\pi i Res_0 f(z)=2\pi i \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\ln z}{\sqrt{z}(1+z)^2} z=0 $ But I'm not sure that this is right

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I checked this in wolfram alpha and there I've got the answer. This integral is equal to $-\pi$

Comment: You may edit your question to include the steps in your comment to avoid closing of this question.

Comment: You may just substitute $x=\tan^2\theta$ and exploit well-known Fourier series to recover $-\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$I(b)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^b}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)^2}\,dx$$
We want to compute $I'(0)$.

Remembering the definition of the Beta function:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}(m,n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}
\end{align}
In our case,
\begin{align}
I(b)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{b-\frac{1}{2}}}{(1+x)^2}\,dx\\
\\
&=\mathcal{B}\left(b+\frac{1}{2},-b+\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(-b+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(2)}\\
\\
&=\Gamma\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(-b+\frac{3}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
I'(b)\Big|_{b=0}&=\Gamma\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)\psi\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(-b+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(-b+\frac{3}{2}\right)\psi\left(-b+\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Biggr|_{b=0}\\
\\
&=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\psi\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
\\
&=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right]\\
\\
&=-\sqrt{\pi}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\qquad\qquad \psi(1+x)-\psi(x)=\frac{1}{x}\\
\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot 2\\
\\
&=\boxed{-\pi}
\end{align}

Thus,
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}(1+x)^2}\,dx=-\pi
\end{align}

Comment: can we solve it without using beta function? I want to teach this question to a High School Student

Comment: You might be able to compute this integral using complex analysis, but I would argue that method is more convoluted then just using the Beta function. I don't think this technique is necessarily beyond what a high school student can study. Instead of appealing to the Beta function directly, maybe they could for example try to understand how the Beta function integral is equal to a ratio of Gamma functions.